# Lua add a variable amount of characters to String

Tags: lua, vertical-alignment

I want to add an amount characters to a print, that equals `space`.

```
if #input >= 1 then
  for var=1, #input, 1 do
    [...]
    av = "was sent"

    else
      av = "doesn't exist"
    end

    space = 20-string.len(input[var])
    print(var..". '"..input[var].."' "..space..av)
  end
return
end
```

my goal is to align `av` vertically. `input[var]`varies in length.

Comment: You need to traverse `input` once to find the max length and then use that to do the alignment in a second traversal.

Comment: @lhf I would assume from their snippet that a max length of 20 is known (and they just don't know how to pad the string)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know that `20` is a maximum length of `input[var]` as your snippet implies, you can directly proceed to padding.

The straightforward solution would be to use `string.rep`:

```lua
print(var..". '"..input[var].."' ".. (" "):rep(space)..av)
```

`string.format` also allows adding padding left and right; using `-x` you can add left padding:

```lua
print(("%s. %-22s %s"):format(var, "'" .. input[var] .. "'", av))
```

Note that I've bumped the padding to 22 since the two single quotes are now included in the calculation.

---

How not to do it:

###### Bad: Quadratic runtime, many garbage strings, more complex / longer code

```lua
local padding = ""
for i = 1, space do padding = padding .. " " end
```

###### Bad: More overhead, garbage table, more complex / longer code

```lua
local t = {}
for i = 1, space do t[i] = " " end
local padding = table.concat(t)
```

---

Side note: If `input[var]` is guaranteed to be a string, you can use `#input[var]` instead of `string.len(input[var])`.

Comment: The existance of `How not to do it` section was quite unexpected.